# Why is the parent div height zero when it has floated children

Tags: html, css

I have the following in my CSS. All margins/paddings/borders are globally reset to 0.

```css
#wrapper{width: 75%; min-width: 800px;}
.content{text-align: justify; float: right; width: 90%;}
.lbar{text-align: justify; float: left; width: 10%;}
```

Now when I write my HTML as

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        some text here
    </div>
    <div class="lbar">
        some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

the page renders correctly. However, when I inspect the elements, `div#wrapper` is shown as being `0px` high. I would've expected it to expand till the end of `div.content` and `div.lbar`... Why does this happen?

Again, the page renders fine. This behaviour just perplexes me.

Comment: This might be useful to you [CSS Floats 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/), from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Content that is floating does not influence the height of its container. The element contains no content that isn't floating (so nothing stops the height of the container being 0, as if it were empty).

Setting `overflow: hidden` on the container will avoid that by establishing a new [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). See [methods for containing floats](http://web.archive.org/web/20161207154227/http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) for other techniques and [containing floats](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) for an explanation about why CSS was designed this way.

Comment: [Here's another approach](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for making containers contain floats that is solved in CSS without having to add elements to the page.

Answer (score 61):

Ordinarily, `float`s aren't counted in the layout of their parents.

To prevent that, add `overflow: hidden` to the parent.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I don't understand why ... overflow:hidden is said to _hide_ the content that overflows, not to enlarge the element to contain it.

Comment: @ripper234 Here is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818199/why-does-overflow-hidden-add-additional-height-to-an-inline-block-element

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure this is a right way but I solved it by adding `display: inline-block;` to the wrapper div.

```css
#wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 1px black solid;*/
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 800px;
}

.content{
    text-align: justify; 
    float: right; 
    width: 90%;
}

.lbar{
    text-align: justify; 
    float: left; 
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: This was the exact solution i've been looking for. Overflow: hidden cause box shadow to vanish, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can

```
#wrapper { display: flow-root; }
```

- Compatibility https://caniuse.com/flow-root
- History https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/