# css floating id causing container to be 0px tall

Tags: css

My id section box is being displayed at 0px even though i have the box itself and all of its parents set to a height of one hundred percent

```
#section_box {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background: #EDEDED;
    width: 992px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[for full page click here](http://www.smyrnainlet.com)

Comment: Your page doesn't appear to be working. This is why we prefer you paste *all relevant code* here in the question.

Comment: Set the container to `overflow:hidden`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369954/why-is-my-divs-height-zero ) and the referenced [link](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Once you float an element, it is no longer counted for its parent's height calculations, unless you put in a clearing element:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="floated" style="float: left">blah blah blah</div>
    <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

Without that `<br>` with the `clear: both`, the #container div will be calculated to be 0-height. With the clearing br, it'll be at least the height of the floated div.

If you don't want to add unecessary markup to your layout, you CAN use `overflow: auto` on the #container div, which has the same effect, as long as you combine it with a `width` directive, as per [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give `height: 100%` to the `html` element