# css positioning issue with float and margin

Tags: css, xhtml

This is my example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YG6tx/5/

so my question is, why is the red div(`pageWrap`) not taking the height of it's inner elements?

If I specify a `float:left`, it takes the height, but the `margin: 0 auto` no longer holds.

how can I acheive both? (`margin:0 auto` + the div needs to take the height ).

Do I need to specify the `height` explicitly?

I'm a newbie, so this question might seem simple.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? It's not clear from your question. Also, the images in the fiddle aren't showing: would it be easier to see what you're expecting if they were?

Comment: I want the `red div` to be centered and it should take the height of it's inner elements. I don't want to explicitly specify the `height` property in css. It is something I'm trying by myself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my div's height zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369954/why-is-my-divs-height-zero)

Comment: @akriy check my updated fiddle and let me know if any changes or help needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YG6tx/12/

As in you original fiddle there were no images due to incorrect path of images so in my fiddle also no images but as per your requirement i have changes the layout.

As per your requirement images are at position, red div taking entire height as per elements inside and center also margin:0 auto;

If i am lagging some where please comment so i can change as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `overflow:hidden` to `#pagewrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Designing with floats and absolutely positioned element is hard... Their parent elements won't wraparound them so often you'd have to specify the height attribute on the parent to accomplish the look you want. However, the `.topLeft` wouldn't exactly need to have the `float:left;` property. If you remove that I think you'll get the desired  look. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YG6tx/8/