# Cant figure out why the background color on my main element won't change

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML and CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyvnma7p/

On line 1-5 I am setting the color of the page to slategrey background. 
The problem is the next line:

```
main {
background: white;
}
```

What this should be doing is taking the main element in my HTML (line 23-48) and changing the middle of the page to white.

What I have tried is changing the CSS tag from main to the div container class element, also with no luck as well.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369963/4378314

Comment: Set overflow:hidden on main, because your children are all float: left and right;

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had no idea this was the same problem - This solves it.

Comment: Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554080/4378314). Going further, today you'd use flexbox to pull off that layout, instead of floats. `justify-content: space-between` would do the same thing and offer all the good flex stuff.